# Finding all obligations in spl-token-lending program

Tags: blockchain, solana

If an `Obligation` becomes unhealthy, it can be liquidated by calling `LiquidateObligation` [instruction](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-lending/program/src/instruction.rs#L266=), however, I cannot liquidate it if I don't know it exists, and the process of finding them is still unclear to me.

What is the expected way for me to find all currently "working" `Obligation`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get all of the `Obligation` accounts is to use the `getProgramAccounts` RPC endpoint with a filter, which fetches every account owned by the lending program that has a certain size.  Since an `Obligation` has a size of 916 according to the code: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/9123a80a6a5b5f8a378a56c4501f99df7debda55/token-lending/program/src/state/obligation.rs#L329, you can do:

```
curl YOUR_RPC_ENDPOINT_HERE -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "LENDING_PROGRAM_PUBKEY_IN_BASE_58",
      {
        "filters": [
          {
            "dataSize": 916
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
'
```

This was adapated from https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#example-35